# iReport with Eclipse: how to use it?

Tags: eclipse, ireport

I'm building GUI an application that produces a report at the end. I tried different way to be able to use the **iReport** using *Eclipse* but unfortunately I haven't succeeded.

**Questions:** 
1.Could someone please guide me by a step by step explanation.
2.Does the *iReport* only work on *NetBeans* and not working on *Eclipse*?

Comment: `2.Does the iReport only work on NetBeans and not working on Eclipse?` - Yes. The *Eclipse-based* version of designer is [Jaspersoft Studio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio).

Comment: `1.Could someone please guide me by a step by step explanation.` - Did you read this guides, for example: [Introduction to Jaspersoft Studio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/introduction-jaspersoft-studio) & [Getting Started with Jaspersoft Studio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/getting-started-jaspersoft-studio)? Did you try to use *Google*?

Answer (score 13):

open Eclipse

1. go Help | Eclipse Marketplace
2. on "Search" tab, Find "ireport", then you will see "Jaspersoft Studio"
3. press "Install"

then go http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-designer-tutorials-help to ready and practice